# Authorization Framework for ASP.NET Application Control Level

Tags: .net, asp.net

I'm looking for the Good Authorization Framework for ASP.NET Application in which in can on/off the control on the web page based on the configuration page(i.e where admin user can set the permission control wise) within the application.

Comment: Can you explain this further? What do you mean exactly by "on/off the control"? What control are we talking about? All controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out Windows Authorization Manager (AzMan).  here's a link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897401.aspx